# conflit jquery wordpress bootstrap

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap into a WordPress theme and I have a conflict between jQuery in wp-include folder and my theme jQuery

this is my function jQuery that need bootstrap.min.js and jquery.js

```
jQuery(function($) {'use strict',

//#main-slider
$(function(){
    $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 8000
    });
}); 
});
```

how could I resolve this problem ?

Comment: whats the 'conflict'? what errors are you getting whats the actual issue?

Comment: What is `Query` and `'use strict',` should be `'use strict';`

Comment: the problem is that i have no error shown in the console

Answer (score 0):

Your code is messy and your redefining what the `$` symbol means.

If you actually wish to redefine the jQuery `$` you can use the [`.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) method.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Make sure your selector is also correct `#main-slider.carousel` would select an element that looks like the following `<div id="main-slider" class="carousel">`. The selector `#main-slider` would achieve the same result.

I suggest you include some HTML in your question. Failing that the code below is my best attempt to answer.

Try the following:

```
'use strict';
jQuery.noConflict(); // If you wish to remove the jQuery '$'.
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#main-slider').carousel({
       interval: 8000
   });
});
```

Comment: Then you'll need to include your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put jQuery into no-conflict mode to use it along with other JS libraries. For example:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is an alias to the jQuery function

$j(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: thank you for responding my code like this now "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is an alias to the jQuery function

$j(document).ready(function() {
   //#main-slider
 
  $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
   interval: 8000
  });
 
});"" and i have the undefinef error in the line "$('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({"

Comment: $j is supposed to be an alias for all $. That means you need to replace all $ occurrences in your code on $j

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for one script is:

```
(function($){
    $(function()){
        //yours code
    });
}(jQuery));
```