# How to fix a JQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep on getting an error message in the chrome console saying that there is an uncaught syntax error. Anybody has any solutions? I am a beginner with JQuery

```
jQuery(function($) {'use strict',

    //#main-slider
    $(function(){
        $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 8000
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? Where is the closing `})` of `jQuery(function($) {`?

Comment: and the comma after `'use strict'` should be a semicolon

Comment: Why do you have `$(function(){...})` *inside* of `jQuery(function($) {...})`?  These are *literally* the same thing and it's pointless to nest them like that.

Comment: That's why I am here, I don't really know how to write jquery, I copied this code and pasted it in mine, but it is giving me errors.

Comment: jQuery isn't a language of its own, it doesn't have any special syntax. It just uses ordinary Javascript function calls.

Comment: Where did you copy & paste this from?

Comment: maybe you should start with learning jquery https://learn.jquery.com/  or even  https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery

Comment: If you need some tutorials, there are some good ones here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: Do you know what you are doing *at all*? This code is copy-pasted from (this question)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364636/conflit-jquery-wordpress-bootstrap].

Answer (score 3):

You have two errors:

1. The comma (`,`) after `'use strict'` should be a semicolon (`;`).
2. You need a closing `});` to match the outermost call to `jQuery`.

Answer (score -3):

Just do:

```
//#main-slider
$(function(){
    $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 8000
    });
});
```

You don't need the other stuff like the JQuery(), from my understanding it's essentially the same as doing $(function(){})

Comment: What does this add to the other answer with the exact same content (which is also incorrect)?

Comment: @cybermonkey the other answer was added after I posted mine.